# how to access the previous value of a document field and update it in a single query in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

i want to update my document field "investorCount" as well as one more updation in the same document in a single mongoose Query .

my update query is

```
  Campaign.update({"campaign.campaign_Id":data.campaignId},{$push: {"campaign.investorsDetails":{investorId: id,investedAmount: Amtinv }},$set : {"campaign.investorCount" : this."campaign.investorCount" + 1 }},function(error,update){
if(error){
    defered.reject(error);
}else{
    console.log(update);
 defered.resolve(update);
}
});
return defered.promise;
}
```

my schema is -

```
var campaignSchema =  new Schema ({
campaign: 
{
campaign_Id :  {type: Number ,index :{unique:true}},
beneficiaryAccount : {type : String , required:true},
createdBy : {type : String },
investorsDetails : [{
    investorId:{type:Number} ,
    investedAmount : {type:Number}
}],
investorCount : {type : Number , default : 0}
}});
```

i use 'this' operator to access the current value of the field but it not work , please help me to solve this

Answer (score 1):

Mongo provides the handy [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operator just for this:

```
$inc : {"campaign.investorCount" : 1 }}
```